# c#, ASP.net with MVC 5.0 - issue with Google Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have managed to connect to the GoogleAPi with webforms but am having an issue with MVC.

```
In theStart.Auth i have put in the following code :


 app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
    {
    ClientId = "6050764343-4ulkmfai2sp2bs.apps.googleusercontent.com",
   ClientSecret = "oDBLHfuU9GTqp9Chcz",
   CallbackPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLoginCallback")
        });
```

getting the following error
The redirect URI in the request, https://localhost:44353/Account/ExternalLoginCallback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.

[image: My oAuth settings on Google]

i have tried to add to add the following in Route.coinfig with same issue...

```
    //routes.MapRoute(
    //name: "signin-google",
    //url: "signin-google",
    //defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "ExternalLoginCallback" });

   also tried commenting out the line below ...when i added the route map.
   CallbackPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLoginCallback")
        });
```

Any insight will be greatly appreciated... Thank you

Comment: please try this CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-google") and no need to change anything in Route config

Answer (score 0):

You Can implement Your External Login With [Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Samples](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples) 
And 
For External Login You Just Need Add ClientId And ClientSecret. Also See This article Code! [MVC 5 App with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)

Comment: Thank-you for your response.. i have tried to follow that article and still get that error... The redirect URI in the request, https://localhost:44353/Account/ExternalLoginCallback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps anyone who is going round in circles because of not checking the default actionName in my case it was ... `ExternalLoginCallback.` once i changed that it all worked.!